# Excel VBA - Format based on cell value (Greater than, less than, equal to)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to all of this, so I will apologise now if I'm being stupid.
I'm having some issues getting the below code to run properly. 
Basically, I'm asking for it to look at one column and;

1. If cells are empty = Colour White
2. If cell value is = to cell in adjacent column then Colour White
3. If cell value is > to cell in adjacent column then Colour Red
4. If cell value is < to cell in adjacent column then Colour Green.

When I run the below code it turns all of the cells red, would anyone be able to explain what I have missed out?

```
    Sub Format_Cells()
    Dim arq As Range
    Dim msl As Range
    Dim Cell

    Set arq = Range("B3:B500")
    Set msl = Range("C3:C500")

    For Each Cell In arq
    'If Cell is blank then Cell Colour = White
        If Cell.Value = "" Then
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        End If
    'If Requisition Quantity is equal to Max Stock Level then Cell Colour = White
        If arq(B3) = msl(C3) Then
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        End If
    'If Requisition Quantity is less than Max Stock Level then Cell Colour = Green
        If arq(B3) < msl(C3) Then
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        End If
    'If Requisition Quantity is more than Max Stock Level then Cell Colour = Red
        If arq(B3) > msl(C3) Then
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
        End If

    Next

     MsgBox "The macro has finished running.", vbInformation
 End Sub
```

Comment: This syntax `arq(B3)` is wrong, but is there any reason why you are not using conditional formatting?

Comment: Hi SJR, Many thanks for you help. 

I should have mentioned in the original post, but basically I'm working on a "1 - click solution" which takes raw data from an eCommerce system, transfers it to a Pivot Table before finally identifying which product lines should have their stock levels increased or decreased.

I could have used conditional formatting, but if possible I want to avoid having the end user do any more than the single button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, CF is probably the way to go, but your existing code as a starting point, I have just amended to use Offset (1 column to the right). Are your four clauses all mutually exclusive?

```
Sub Format_Cells()

Dim arq As Range
Dim msl As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Set arq = Range("B3:B500")
Set msl = Range("C3:C500")

For Each Cell In arq
'If Cell is blank then Cell Colour = White
    If Cell.Value = vbnullstring Then
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    End If
'If Requisition Quantity is equal to Max Stock Level then Cell Colour = White
    If Cell.Value = Cell.Offset(, 1).Value Then
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    End If
'If Requisition Quantity is less than Max Stock Level then Cell Colour = Green
    If Cell.Value < Cell.Offset(, 1).Value Then
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
    End If
'If Requisition Quantity is more than Max Stock Level then Cell Colour = Red
    If Cell.Value > Cell.Offset(, 1).Value Then
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
    End If
Next

MsgBox "The macro has finished running.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll give this a go and will let you know the outcomes.

Comment: Worked perfectly, All I need to do now is force the pivot table to round up to a whole number rather than to two decimal points. 

Many thanks for your help SJR.